# NSDateFormatter date format type

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I am trying to set the date format for something like "2013-12-02T12:15:43.182Z. I used that code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssS''Z'"];
```

How can i set this date format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ues this:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *dateConverted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-12-02T12:15:43.182Z"];
NSLog(@"%@",dateConverted);
```

Comment: dateFromString:@"2013-12-02T12:15:43.182Z" --why this ? if i need it to be system date then what?

Comment: You can pass any date string which have above datefromat.

Comment: The single quotes are only needed around 'T'. @Zafer Fatih Koyuncu has it right.

Comment: Additionally the single quotes around the 'Z' produce the wrong hour, 17 instead of 12. NSLog output" 2013-12-02 17:15:43 +0000"

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSLog(@"Required date format: %@",[df stringFromDate:myDate]);
```